# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined | React, Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am getting the error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`. I understand that is has to do with the array (`posts`) mapping over is empty:

```
const postsList = posts.map((postList, i) => {
```

My action looks like this:

```
const setPosts = data => {
  return {
    type: 'SET_POSTS',
    payload: {
      setPosts: data
    }
  }
}

export const fetchPosts = () => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const posts = await axios.get(`${settings.hostname}/api/posts`)
    dispatch(setPosts(posts.data))
  } catch (err) {
    throw err
  }
}
```

My reducer:

```
const initialState = {}

export const fetchPosts = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_POSTS':
      return { ...state, posts: action.payload.setPosts }

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

And in my component (the most important stuffs):

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.fetchPosts()
}

PostLayout.propTypes = {
  props: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  fetchPosts: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    posts: state.fetchPosts.posts,
    isLoading: state.fetchPostsIsLoading
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    fetchPosts: () => dispatch(fetchPosts())
  }
}
```

The weird part is that I can see it here:

```
const posts = this.props.posts || []
console.log(posts)
```

First its an empty array, but later it gets filled with data. So I wonder how I can fix this frustrating error so I can map over my data.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: My react isn't up to par for me to guess how these files depend on each other and trace it through, but I see pretty clearly that `fetchPosts()` in your `action` file is returning a promise. You might be able to pass that promise along so you can do `.then(/* get my props*/ )`

Answer (score 0):

Your component is probably calling `postsList.map` before the AJAX fetch has completed on its initial render (hard to tell because you don't show us the component). Components render when mounted, they don't want for dispatches to complete. Simply do something like

```
if( !postList || this.props.isLoading ) {
    return <div>loading</div>;
}
```

Comment: How can I use `!postList` if I don't have any array to map over and then store in `propsList`?

Comment: Also, I tried with that, but the loading screen is not going away even if I'm getting my posts.

Comment: the `!postList` piece says "if postList has not been defined yet", so @AndyRay 's bit of code says "if postlist hasn't been populated yet, just render 'loading' "

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that is has to do with the array (posts) mapping over is
>   empty:

It is not empty. It is undefined.

Just set `posts` in your initial state to empty array :)

```
const initialState = {
  posts: [],
}
```

this way you will avoid error and won't have to do additional checks.